# Is it possible from a native application (C++) on linux to call a .NET library

Tags: .net, linux

we have a .NET library running on Windows.
We'd like to use on Linux but wonder whether it is possible to call it (a .NET library) from a native (C++) application.
On Windows it is possible to use COM if your language is not .NET compatible but what about Linux ?

Comment: Have a look at [pinvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) In mono you are able to do so, as well as in .NET Core

Comment: This seems to be calling unmanaged code from managed code (C++ from C# for instance). What we want to do is call the C# library from C++, on Linux. On a PC Delphi can't call .NET so you can use COM to get an callable interface, we want to know whether there's something like that on Linux we can use. Or maybe can we easily call the library from some native code, but then what do we have to do for that ?

Comment: Currently I'm running into the same question. I think it's not possible, because for the call to the managed library the .NET runtime would be required to run within the same process. A workaround is writing a service, which makes the API available using pipes or sockets. I wonder if there'll be a better solution for non-Windows OS later - such as a permanent .NET runtime service and something like a COM interface.

Comment: Creating a service is actually what I just did and it works great. But a .NET native service to do that would be interesting, normalizing the way to exchange data indeed.